# Magento2.2 configurable products out of stock issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I am working on Magento 2.2 I install https://github.com/interjar/configurable-child-visibility module to show Configurable child products visibility when out of stock and its working fine  I want to make the option none clickable if the product is out of stock is there something that is possible with this module. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you found the solution for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured this out. I am posting this here if anyone else is facing the same issue. Maybe this will help. Here is the link that solves the problem for me.
    https://github.com/mjankiewicz/MagentoConfigurableProduct

Comment: will it work on Swatches as well?

Comment: I tried this module but no luck, its not working for me

Comment: this is not showing the out of stock child item also.

Comment: Yes it is working for Swatches as well

Comment: doesn't work for 2.2.5

Comment: Works for 2.3 (I modified the code to show out of stock options), but requires a cache flush before script changes are applied =)

Comment: Given github link does not exist. Please update.