# Show out of Stock Configurable products magento2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, out-of-stock

I am trying to show out of stock child item of configurable product.

referred below link

[Magento2.2 configurable products out of stock issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240597/magento2-2-configurable-products-out-of-stock-issue)

As the answer is accepted there. Used same module in my case.

Still the child products which are out of stock are not being shown.

Can anybody help me please. Thanks

I have set in Configuration to show out of stock products.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem so I created a module to fix it. It's available from here: https://github.com/pkarsai/show-out-of-stock-products-magento2

Tested with Magento 2.2.7.

See this my answer to a similar question for more info: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/268626/63748

Comment: Please don't past the same  content to the different questions.

Comment: Why not if the questions have the same answer? I found these questions when trying to find a solution to this problem and when I finally reached a solution I wanted to share it with all people who ran into the same problem. What's wrong with that?